# ionic angular factory return undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I got a view where I render a google map which then should check the location of the device periodically.

Controller

```
.controller('SearchCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, TrackLocation) {
    //document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    //function onDeviceReady() {

        //Loads Google Map
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
            zoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

        var myPost = TrackLocation.track();
        console.log(myPost);
    //}
})
```

Factory

```
.factory('TrackLocation', function($http, $cordovaGeolocation) {
    return {
        track: function() {

            console.log("Started Tracking");
            var lat, long;

            var watchOptions = {
                timeout : 3000,
                enableHighAccuracy: true
            };

            var watch = $cordovaGeolocation.watchPosition(watchOptions);
            watch.then(
            null,
            function(err) {
                console.log(err);
                return "lole";
            },
            function(position) {
                lat  = position.coords.latitude
                long = position.coords.longitude
                console.log(lat);
            });
            return {'lat': lat, 'long':long };
        },
        stop: function() {

        }
    };

})
```

Console Log

```
Started Tracking
Object {lat: undefined, long: undefined}
103 14.408132700000001
```

the myPost was return with an undefined value because it was called before the real value was pass on the lat.

Please help.

Comment: you return result before `watch.then` complete and you setup your variables

Comment: i tried putting the `return {'lat': lat, 'long':long };` inside the `function(position)` and giving me a plain undefined.. not an object but plain undefined.

Comment: sure, because in this case you do return from `watch` callback, instead `track` function

Comment: but you can do the trick with async console: instead primitive value `lat` and `long` use object like : `var coord = {lat:'', long:''}` and in callback: `coord.lat  = position.coords.latitude
                coord.long = position.coords.longitude` and instead `return {'lat': lat, 'long':long };` use `return coord;`. now when you expand value in console: you would see current value for properties, so if promise not solve it would be empty string, if resolve - needed value

Answer (score 0):

You should return just watch in your track method or return promise and than in success callback resolve this promise with lat and long values.